# Why is the difference in memory address' of two elements of a char array 4?

Tags: c, arrays, memory

I was messing around in C trying to find a way to interpret the difference in memory address' when finding two array elements next to each other and finding the difference. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char *a[5];
  printf("%p\n", (&a[0]));
  printf("%p\n", (&a[1]));
  return 0;
}
```

And example output:

```
0xbf9343dc
0xbf9343e0
```

When doing this, shouldn't the output be something to the form:

```
0x0....0
0x0....1
```

Because the size of a char pointer should be 1 (on a 32-bit system which I am using).

If anyone knows why this is the case and can offer an explanation it would be very helpful

Comment: I guess you wanted to ask ` Why is the difference in memory address' of two elements of a char* array 4?`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The size of a `char` is `1`, the size of  a `char *` is implementation dependent, usually `4` in `32`-bit system.

Comment: Or to elucidate a bit more, you have an array of character pointers declared, not an array of characters.  Hence, each element of the array is a pointer, and as @ouah points out, the size of a pointer is usually `4` in a `32`-bit system.

Comment: Huh, never noticed that before. If I were to be using a 64-bit system would the pointer then be 8 bytes because a char is 2?

Comment: @Sythe yes, a 64 bit pointer is 8 bytes, and **no**, a char is still 1 byte

Comment: @Sythe The size of a `char` is always `1`.

Answer (score 3):

You'll get the results you expect if you declare an array of char instead of an array of char *.  Note the line `char a[5]`.

```
$ cat foo.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char a[5];
  printf("%p\n", (&a[0]));
  printf("%p\n", (&a[1]));
  return 0;
}

$ foo
0x7fff5e1119d7
0x7fff5e1119d8
```

`char a[5]` holds 5 characters.  `char *a[5]` hold 5 pointers to characters.